# What are the "dctp" and "did" files in my Android storage?

Tags: storage, 7.1-nougat, miui, miui-10

I have noticed two strange files in my Android storage. They are named "dctp" and "did". They don't have any extensions and my programs cannot read them. What are those files and what are their purposes?

Comment: It appears to me that those two files are present only in Xiaomi phones. https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22dctp%22+%22did%22+android&atb=v151-5__&ia=web

Comment: These files are created by some of init daemons or some app on phones with MIUI ROM. I hade figured that out but can't remember exactly because I haven't been using MIUI for quite a while now. These files contain some plain text strings I think. You can delete them safely but they will reappear on reboot.